# Do we need a special syntax highlighter for cooking?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Currently the syntax highlighter is the same used for programming languages. Which means that the following looks a bit weird:

```
Fish and eggs
```

Should the syntax highlighter be disabled, should we make a "food"-syntax (which highlights 'stir', 'add', 'mix', 'bake', etc) or should code just be code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We usually disable the syntax highlighting unless the topic is code-y.

We neglected to do that here, but I'll fix it.

Answer (score 9):

I would love to see a "code" mode that highlighted recipes. It would have to be very simple. Basically, a format that allows for clear reading of ingredients.

It could simply color the first column (amounts) and second column (ingredients) differently, and possibly use a third style for the instructions. Further highlighting of keywords might be useful, but I don't have any suggestions at the moment.

Comment: I second that. Highlighting and standardizing words like stir, fry, tbsp, etc. would make the site look much more appealing.

Comment: I think this is a great idea +1

Comment: I'd also like to see an XML format for recipes .. that could be good ;)

Answer (score 4):

Many years ago, at MIT, there was a parody of the Honeywell 68K instruction set called the 'cuisinart 2000 processor'. It had instructions like:

```
tbsp 2
stir 10
```

etc.